# JSON-LD doesn't work after API call in Angular universal

Tags: json, angular, angular-universal, json-ld

I'm using Angular 7 and Angular universal, and am going to implement the Google Structured Data using JSON-LD.

The JSON-LD is not static and need to get values through API.
Btw static JSON-LD works well but after API call, it doesn't work.

- **app.component.html**

```
<ngx-json-ld [json]="schema"></ngx-json-ld>
```

- **app.component.ts**

```
this._appService.getAPI(`${this.storyApiUrl}`).subscribe(result => {
    const json = {
          '@context': 'https://schema.org/',
          '@type': 'Article',
          'headline': result.meta.seo.title,
          'name': result.meta.seo.author,
          'datePublished': result.data.posted_on,
          'dateModified': result.data.posted_on,
       ...
    }
...
```

Please help me!

Comment: You have issue with API side. Describe the use of API keys for controlling API versions, rather than the use of different versioned URLs.

Comment: Check if you have no error in the console server side

Comment: Can you clarify "doesn't work". Note that the Structured Data Testing Tool is very bad at JavaScript, so don't test using that directly. Get hold of the rendered content of the page and test with that instead.

Comment: Yes, I already tested the rendered content and there was no content in **ld+JSON** script tag.

Comment: Hi @SergioReis I had the same issue , I have changed to instance the data after view init https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit  and worked for my case